# Change Child node width in an HBOX

Tags: javafx

I am trying to change hbox cell width via changing child node width in the hbox

```
Hbox hbox = new Hbox(new Label("node1"), new Label(node2), new Label(node3));
//Lets say I wanna change the lable says "node3"

//i tried below option. did not work
hbox.getChildren().get(2).maxWidth(150);
```

Comment: `maxWidth` is a method for calculating the max width of the node. An invocation does not result in a update of any of the node's properties. To change the max width you need to use `Region.setMaxWidth` and even then there's no guarantee that a) there's enough room to grow the label and b) The `Label` grows beyond the preferred size the `Label` is proably resized to at that moment. c) Resizing the label when there is enough room to display the text doesn't have any effect, except the label's boundary property being larger (and possibly positioning children added later differently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node.maxWidth() is invoked by layouts to query the maximum size of the node, to change child width (label) cast it then use the setter

```
((Label) hBox.getChildren().get(2)).setPrefWidth(150);
```

Comment: Thanx mate.it did work. for those who bind the width property to the parent node should use setMaxWidth(150).